# How many connection pools can be created in ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, connection-pooling

I understand that a connection pool can have 100 physical connections by default. How many pools can be created in ADO.NET? Does it related to the available memory of the machine.

I've learnt that the implementation for connection pooling is based on the provider so how SQL data provider's connection pooling work will be different from how Oledb's connection pooling. (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) The default max physical connections for a pool is 100. If we have different connection strings (or different string order but same database) or different windows identity (if we are using windows authentication), new connection pool will be created. but I am looking for the information about how many connection pool can be created...

Please let me know if you are not clear what I'm asking or need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Max Pool Size doesn't limit the number of pools you can create—that limit is determined by the number of SQL Server connections that your sa setting or license makes available (about 32,768 per cluster)." http://www.sqlmag.com/content1/topic/swimming-in-the-net-connection-pool/catpath/activex/page/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Schmelter stated, there is no maximum value for the `MaxPoolSize`.

It all depends on the maximum number of concurrent connections to a single SQL Server. So 32767 would be the maximum value to assign to the `MaxPoolSize`.

See `User connections` in the [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) documentation.